# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (ligne 8, fichier "AGENDA.gs")

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax-error

To begin with, excuse my English because I am French and I am writing this message to you using Google Translate. (My English is too bad)

I am asking you because i have a big problem with google app script.

I'm new to the script, and I'm trying to create an event on google calendar using info from a sheet.

My problem is that I can't understand where the error is in my script.

The error message is as follows :
" SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (ligne 8, fichier "AGENDA.gs") "

My code is as follows :

```
function event (){
  
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ws.getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();
  
  for (var i=2; i<=lr; i++) {
    
       var nom = ws.getRange(i; 1).getValue();
       var contenu = ws.getRange(i; 2).getValue();
       var debut = ws.getRange(i; 3).getValue()+" "+ws.getRange(i; 4).getValue();
       var fin = ws.getRange(i; 3).getValue()+" "+ws.getRange(i; 5).getValue();
       var invites = ws.getRange(i; 6).getValue();
       var lieu = ws.getRange(i; 10).getValue();
    
    var agenda = CalendarApp.createEvent(nom, debut, fin,{description : contenu,
                                                          location : lieu,
                                                          guests : invites,
                                                          sendInvites : true});
    
    agenda.setColor('11');
    agenda.addPopupReminder(60);
    
    ws.getRange(i, 7).setValue(true);
    
  }
  
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: Look at all the places where you have a `;` instead of a `,` - for example: `ws.getRange(i; 1)`.

Comment: I've posted an answer to your problem, but unless I'm able to see all of your code I can't be sure it will help. If my answer does not help you if you post more of your code I will update my answer to more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You problem is in the `getRange()` method. `;` tells javascript that its time to move onto the next line. So the inside of your for loop looks like this:

```
var nom = ws.getRange(i;
1).getValue();
var contenu = ws.getRange(i;
2).getValue();
var debut = ws.getRange(i;
3).getValue()+" "+ws.getRange(i;
4).getValue();
var fin = ws.getRange(i;
3).getValue()+" "+ws.getRange(i;
5).getValue();
var invites = ws.getRange(i;
6).getValue();
var lieu = ws.getRange(i;
10).getValue();
```

**Answer**

If you swap `;` => `,` inside the `getRange` function this will be no longer a problem. The fixed `event` function looks like this:

```
function event (){
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lr = ws.getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();

    for (var i=2; i<=lr; i++) {

        var nom = ws.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
        var contenu = ws.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        var debut = ws.getRange(i, 3).getValue() + " "+ws.getRange(i, 4 ).getValue();
        var fin = ws.getRange(i, 3).getValue() + " " + ws.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
        var invites = ws.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
        var lieu = ws.getRange(i, 10).getValue();

        var agenda = CalendarApp.createEvent(nom, debut, fin,{description : contenu,
            location : lieu,
            guests : invites,
            sendInvites : true});

        agenda.setColor('11');
        agenda.addPopupReminder(60);
        ws.getRange(i, 7).setValue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, the error message has disappeared, however my code does not work on the event creation part in google calendar and I do not understand why

Comment: If you post all your code I will fix it completely